# Async network operations never finish

Tags: c#, networking, async-await, idisposable, cancellation-token

I have several asynchronous network operations that return a task that may never finish:

1. `UdpClient.ReceiveAsync` doesn't accept a `CancellationToken`
2. `TcpClient.GetStream` returns a `NetworkStream` that doesn't respect the `CancellationToken` on `Stream.ReadAsync` (checking for cancellation only at the start of the operation)

Both wait for a message that **may** never come (because of packet loss or no response for example). That means I have *phantom* tasks that never complete, continuations that will never run and used sockets on hold. I know i can use [`TimeoutAfter`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx), but that will only fix the continuation problem.

So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: At least, TcpClient will throw an exception (or return 0 in stream.Read) eventually. so there won't be any *phantom* tasks. Assuming you create only one `UdpClient` in your application one *phantom* task isn't a problem. If you think i am wrong please post a real case(+code) so that we can make concrete answers.

Comment: @L.B It won't in `stream.ReadAsync` (added to the question). And i use both tcp and udp concurrently hundreds of times a second.

Comment: Sorry but I have written millions of codes using TcpClient or UdpClient but i never needed a method like this (of course in services running 24/7). BTW: `packet loss` doesn't apply to TCP

Comment: I assure you i didn't invent my situation. I ran out of udp ports while performance testing.

Comment: I guess it is because you don't know the internals of protocols and do not use the classes properly. I think no need to continue this discussion when there is no real case to talk about. Anyway, If it solves your problem than it is good enough.

Comment: @L.B, packet loss does apply to TCP, but it's handled transparently to the application layer.

Comment: @NathanErnst Of course, everybody knows this. What happens when it is unrecovarable is explained in my first comment's first sentense.

Comment: @L.B that sentence is not relevant if you use `async-await`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So i've made an extension method on `IDisposable` that creates a `CancellationToken` that disposes the connection on timeout, so the task finishes and everything carries on:

```
public static IDisposable CreateTimeoutScope(this IDisposable disposable, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeSpan);
    var cancellationTokenRegistration = cancellationTokenSource.Token.Register(disposable.Dispose);
    return new DisposableScope(
        () =>
        {
            cancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose();
            cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            disposable.Dispose();
        });
}
```

And the usage is extremely simple:

```
try
{
    var client = new UdpClient();
    using (client.CreateTimeoutScope(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
    {
        var result = await client.ReceiveAsync();
        // Handle result
    }
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException)
{
    return null;
}
```

---

Extra Info:

```
public sealed class DisposableScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _closeScopeAction;
    public DisposableScope(Action closeScopeAction)
    {
        _closeScopeAction = closeScopeAction;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _closeScopeAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant hac...uh...solution! It never occurred to me to dispose the offending bad actor. Disruptive, but very effective! I suppose it would be pointless to try/catch the _closeScopeAction (my first inclination when providing an action-based API). I guess anything that barfs there should be exposed in a most obvious way as soon as possible.

Comment: @Clay I agree. If it can't actually handle the exception it shouldn't catch it. You may also want to look at this related question: [Is it safe to call BeginXXX without calling EndXXX if the instance is already disposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30226894/885318)

Comment: @Blue It may. Dispose should be able to be called twice.

Answer (score 3):

> So what am I supposed to do?

In this particular case, I would rather use `UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout` and `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` to time out a UDP or TCP receive operation gracefully. I'd like to have the time-out error coming from the socket, rather than from any external source.

If in addition to that I need to observe some other cancellation event, like a UI button click, I would just use `WithCancellation` from Stephen Toub's ["How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations), like this:

```
using (var client = new UdpClient())
{
    UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;

    var result = await client.ReceiveAsync().WithCancellation(userToken);
    // ...
}
```

**To address the comment**, in case `ReceiveTimeout` has no effect on `ReceiveAsync`, I'd still use `WithCancellation`:

```
using (var client = new UdpClient())
using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(userToken))
{
    UdpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;
    cts.CancelAfter(2000);

    var result = await client.ReceiveAsync().WithCancellation(cts.Token);
    // ...
}
```

IMO, this more clearly shows my intentions as a developer and is more readable to a 3rd party. Also, I don't need to catch `ObjectDisposedException` exeception. I still need to observe `OperationCanceledException` somewhere in my client code which calls this, but I'd be doing that anyway. `OperationCanceledException` usually stands out from other exceptions, and I have an option to check `OperationCanceledException.CancellationToken` to observe the reason for cancellation.

Other than that, there's not much difference from @I3arnon's answer. I just don't feel like I need another pattern for this, as I already have [`WithCancellation`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations) at my disposal.

**To further address the comments:**

- I'd only be catching `OperationCanceledException` in the client code, i.e.:

async void Button_Click(sender o, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            await DoSocketStuffAsync(_userCancellationToken.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            while (ex is AggregateException)
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            if (ex is OperationCanceledException)
                return; // ignore if cancelled
            // report otherwise
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

- Yes, I'll be using `WithCancellation` with each `ReadAsync` call and I like that fact, for the following reasons. Firstly, I can create an extension `ReceiveAsyncWithToken`:

```
public static class UdpClientExt
{
    public static Task<UdpReceiveResult> ReceiveAsyncWithToken(
        this UdpClient client, CancellationToken token)
    {
        return client.ReceiveAsync().WithCancellation(token);
    }
}
```

Secondly, in 3yrs from now I may be reviewing this code for .NET 6.0. By then, Microsoft may have a new API, `UdpClient.ReceiveAsyncWithTimeout`. In my case, I'll simply replace `ReceiveAsyncWithToken(token)` or `ReceiveAsync().WithCancellation(token)` with `ReceiveAsyncWithTimeout(timeout, userToken)`. It would not be so obvious to deal with `CreateTimeoutScope`.

Comment: Timeouts are only relevant to synchronous operations, not async ones: "This option applies to synchronous Receive calls only. If the time-out period is exceeded, the Receive method will throw a SocketException." from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @l3arnon, I updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: `WithCancellation` though won't really cancel the `ReceiveAsync` *phantom* task, it only allows to "abandon" it, just like `TimeoutAfter` (also by toub)

Comment: @l3arnon, it will cancel in it the same way your `DisposableScope` will: `client.Dispose` will be called as soon as the corresponding `using` scope ends. Which will end as soon as `WithCancellation` throws a `TaskCancelledException`. This way, I don't have to observe `ObjectDisposedException` as you do.

Comment: You would need to observe `TaskCancelledException` though, and then.. what's really the difference between our answers.

Comment: btw.. That's what i used to do, but i thought clearly stating that im calling dispose is clearer than it being implied by closing the using scope.

Comment: @I3arnon, I moved my last comment to the answer.

Comment: Last 2 things: 1. I get why you would like CanceledException, but not why you would be catching it anyway (I don't). 2. Your solution means that you need to add `WithCancellation` to every single async call in that scope (for example `tcpClient.ConnectAsync`, `SendAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`).

Comment: @I3arnon, if you're still interested, I further updated the answer to address your latest comments.

Comment: I laughed at the ".NET 6.0" part. Well said. One should hope that by then Microsoft don't bring back the old UnobservedTaskException behaviour, because then a lot of people using `WithCancellation` (and not handling the exceptions thrown inside the abandoned task, i.e. `ObjectDisposedException` in this case) will be kicking themselves.