# Cancel a speechrecognizer task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I have a WP8 app, which uses the UI-less version of the `SpeechRecognizer`. I use the following code:

```
string[] commands = { "Shoot" };
recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
await speechOutput.SpeakTextAsync("You can say Shoot.");
recognizer.Grammars.AddGrammarFromList("captureCommands", commands);
SpeechRecognitionResult result = await recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

if (result.Text == "Shoot")
   cam.CaptureImage();
```

This prompts the user in both speech and on-screen text that he can say "Shoot" to take a photo. Three other options are:

1. Tap the screen to shoot
2. Click the shoot button in the `ApplicationBar`
3. Click the a button on the `ApplicationBar` to choose from the photo library

In all three cases I would like to cancel the speech recognizer task.
I tried removing the `await` and casting the `IAsyncOperation<SpeechRecognitionResult>` to a `Task<SpeechRecognitionResult>`, but since I don't create the task and the method does not take a cancellation token, I don't know how to cancel it, even now that I have the task object.

If I don't cancel the task and navigate away from the page, I get an App level exception. Is there a way I can explicitly cancel the task or awaited operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't cancel a non-cancelable async operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx).
If the method doesn't take a cancellation token you can't basically cancel it.
What you can do is:

1. Abandon the operation using `WithCancellation` or [`WithTimeout`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx).
2. Dispose the `SpeechRecognizer` (which is an `IDisposable`) and catch its `ObjectDisposedException`.

---

Here's my solution to a similar, though not the same, problem: [Async network operations never finish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468138/885318)

Comment: Yes, I gathered as much. Well, it would pain me to do this workaround, since it feels so wrong, but I guess that's what I`ll end up doing :) Thank you!