# How to cancel MoveNext operation on tailable cursor

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm implementing PubSub using MongoDB.  If I create my query specifying a TailableCursor with NoCursorTimeout:

```
using(var enumerator = _Collection.FindAs<BsonDocument>(Query.GTE("CreationTimeUTC", DateTime.UtcNow))
    .SetFlags(QueryFlags.AwaitData | QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout | QueryFlags.TailableCursor)
    .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural")).GetEnumerator))
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
             //process the message here
        }
    }
}
```

MoveNext() blocks indefinitely (or until data is available or an error occurs).  If I want to force MoveNext() to return (for instance, if I want to cancel listening) how do I do it?    Call Dispose() on the enumerator or the cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set a timeout on the cursor then that's pretty much all you can do, as long as the `MoveNext` method doesn't accept a `CancellationToken`.
Just dispose of the enumerator, catch the `ObjectDisposedException` and move on.

I have a solution example for a similar case [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21468138/885318) Which in this case would be:

```
try
{
    using(enumerator.CreateTimeoutScope(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)))
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                 //process the message here
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException)
{
}
```